# If $b \sin B=a \sin(2A+B)$ then prove that...

Tags: trigonometry

If $b \sin B=a \sin(2A+B)$ then prove that:
$ \cot(A+B)=\frac {b-a}{b+a}\cdot\cot A$

My Approach.
Given,
$$b \sin B=a \sin(2A+B)$$
$$b \sin B=a \sin2A\cdot\cos B+a \cos2A\cdot\sin B$$
$$b \sin B-a \cos2A\cdot\sin B=a \sin2A\cdot\cos B$$
$$\ \sin B(b-a\cos2A)=a \sin2A\cdot\cos B$$
$$b-a \cos2A=a \sin2A\cdot\cot B$$

I got stuck at here. Please help me to complete.

Comment: Try writing $2A+B = (A+B)+A$ and use sine addition on that sum instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$b\sin(\underbrace{A+B}-A)=a\sin(\underbrace{A+B}+A)$$

$$\iff\dfrac ba=\dfrac{\sin(\underbrace{A+B}+A)}{\sin(\underbrace{A+B}-A)}$$

Use [Componendo and Dividendo](https://brilliant.org/wiki/componendo-an-d-dividendo/) $$\dfrac{b+a}{b-a}=\dfrac{\sin(\underbrace{A+B}+A)+\sin(\underbrace{A+B}-A)}{\sin(\underbrace{A+B}+A)-\sin(\underbrace{A+B}-A)}=\dfrac{2\sin(A+B)\cos A}{2\cos(A+B)\sin A}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Is your application of componendo and dividendo correct, in $3$rd step?

Comment: @user354073, Please find the updated answer.

Comment: Ok. That's beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from your last step -

$b-a\cos{2A}=a\sin{2A}\cot{B}$

$b=a(\cos{2A}+\sin{2A}\cot{B})$

$\dfrac{b}{a}=\dfrac{\cos{2A}+\sin{2A}\cot{B}}{1}$

$\dfrac{b+a}{b-a}=\dfrac{\cos{2A}+\sin{2A}\cot{B}+1}{\cos{2A}+\sin{2A}\cot{B}-1}$

$\dfrac{b+a}{b-a}=\dfrac{\sin{2A}\cot{B}+(1+\cos{2A})}{\sin{2A}\cot{B}-(1-\cos{2A})}$

$\dfrac{b+a}{b-a}=\dfrac{\sin{2A}\cot{B}+2\cos^2{A}}{\sin{2A}\cot{B}-2\sin^2{A}}$

$\dfrac{b+a}{b-a}=\dfrac{2\sin{A}\cos{A}\cot{B}+2\cos^2{A}}{2\sin{A}\cos{A}\cot{B}-2\sin^2{A}}$

$\dfrac{b+a}{b-a}=\dfrac{\cos{A}(\sin{A}\cot{B}+\cos{A})}{\sin{A}(\cos{A}\cot{B}-\sin{A})}$

$\dfrac{\cos{A}\cot{B}-\sin{A}}{\sin{A}\cot{B}+\cos{A}}=\cot{A}\times\dfrac{b-a}{b+a}$

Divide the left fraction's numerator and denominator by $\sin{A}$ to get your answer.